# Div is not taking full width when the window is resize to half in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Why the *div*  is not talking full width when the window is resize to half . I am using **tailwindcss** utility classes.  I wonder what's the reason behind this since in full window size its working fine and how to fix it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
   <div class="header bg-red-300 h-12 container">Todoer</div>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Please run the code in full window to notice the effect and then resize its to half.

Comment: why not specifying `w-full`?

Comment: @SinanYaman using `w-full` is not working either. After some research I found out It's something related to the class `container` tailwind css is using some breakpoints ( idk exactly whats happening) . Here is the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container

Comment: @Tjsm because container is designed to have `max-width`. If you need to have full screen width element, just remove `container` class

Comment: _idk exactly whats happening_  That's why you never should use frameworks as you start learning coding. Start using the vanilla css first. If you master that, you could start using a framework.